# Using a variables name as part of another variable name

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to make a unique variable throughout my javascript.

I have >

```
var myfilename = "Report_Product_Daily";
var myfilename + spinner2 = $("<div id='spin1' class=\"activeSpinner\">\n\n<div id='spinborder1' class=\"spinner border1\"><\/div>\n\n<\/div>;");
```

The myfilename is the variable i want before all my variables.

Is this possible?

Mark

Comment: Note that this is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: What's wrong with a unique member of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need somewhere to store it, possibly the `window`:

```
window[myfilename + 'spinner2'] = .....
```

or another object

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[myfilename + 'spinner2'] = .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var myVar = {},myfilename = "Report_Product_Daily";
myVar[myfilename + "spinner2"] = $("<div id='spin1' class=\"activeSpinner\">\n\n<div id='spinborder1' class=\"spinner border1\"><\/div>\n\n<\/div>;");
```

You CAN use the window object but it is considered polluting.

UPDATE: Perhaps THIS is what you want?

```
var Report_Product_Daily = {}
Report_Product_Daily["spinner2"] = $("<div id='spin1' ....
```

PS: This is better syntax:

```
$('<div id="spin1" class="activeSpinner"><div id="spinborder1" class="spinner border1"></div></div>;')
```

Comment: Thank you but what if i have lots of variables would i just do myvar[filename + spinner5] = blah blah;

Comment: yes with quotes. `myvar[filename + "spinner5"]`  - for an alternative see update ....